# Get message author in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a fun bot for just me and my friends. I want to have a command that says what the authors username is, with or without the tag. I tried looking up how to do this, but none worked with the way my code is currently set up.

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$WhoAmI'):
        ##gets author.
        await message.channel.send('You are', username)

client.run('token')
```

I hope this makes sense, all of the code i have seen is using the `ctx` or `@client.command`

Comment: Have you tried `discord.Message.author.name`?

Comment: another issue with this is that its just inline with the regular flow of the program, your `if` should be in the `on_message` `@client.event`, see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot)

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge I edited it and fixed it. My script is correct i just forgot to include it when posting my question, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @Daniil That isn't an instance of a message, that's just the message object.

Comment: @Daniil I got an error, `Class 'Message' has no 'author' member`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works on `discord.py` v1.3.3

`message.channel.send` isn't like `print`, it doesn't accept multiple arguments and create a string from it. Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create one string and send that back to the channel.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$WhoAmI'):
        await message.channel.send('You are {}'.format(message.author.name))

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just:

```
import discord
from discord import commands

client = commands.Bot(case_insensitive=True, command_prefix='$')

@client.command()
async def whoAmI(ctx):
   await ctx.send(f'You are {ctx.message.author}')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ping the user:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('$WhoAmI'):
        await message.channel.send('You are', message.author.mention)

client.run('token')
```